# How to Insert xml top level attribute nodes using a column value from other table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, nodes

I have a particular XML value, containing a namespace like this :

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
<s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="30">
  <s:AttributeType name="ows_ID" rs:name="ID" rs:number="1">
    <s:datatype dt:type="i4" dt:maxLength="4" />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name="ows_Title" rs:name="Title" rs:number="4">
    <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" />
  </s:AttributeType>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
  <z:row ows_ID="1" ows_Title="aaa" />
  <z:row ows_ID="2" ows_Title="bbb />
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

In another table, I have value:

```
Title             newAttr1              newAttr2
aaa               this is a sample      1
bbb               this is another       2
```

My goal is to have:

```
  <z:row ows_ID="1" ows_Title="aaa" ows_newAttr1="this is a sample" ows_newAttr2="1" />
  <z:row ows_ID="2" ows_Title="bbb" ows_newAttr1="this is another" ows_newAttr2="2"/>
```

I tried different ways with myXML.update, but still have errors.
Can it be done?

thanks in advance.
regards,

Comment: *"I tried different ways with myXML.update, but still have errors. Can it be done?"* What *were* those attempts? What were the errors you received?

Comment: XMLValue.modify()]: Only non-document nodes can be inserted. Found "xs:boolean".

Comment: Or is there a way to read a full row return to table ? (each attribute as column name, and each value as value) ? And vice-versa ?

Comment: [Edit] your post, include your full attempts and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below url, will help you and let me know if still you have any query.

http://etutorials.org/Programming/Web+Solutions+based+on+ASP.NET+and+ADO.NET/Part+III+Interoperability/Interoperable+Web+Applications/From+DataSet+Objects+to+ADO+Recordset+Objects/

Comment: Please write out your question on this site and not refer to an outside site to ask your question. In the future that site may not exist anymore and other people won't be able to benefit from your question and others answers.